# What does "capacity" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> As stated we operate solely in a **Business-to-Business capacity**, our
>   marketing communications are sent to professional email addresses ...
>
> (http://www.antoniofalco.com/privacy-policy/)
>
> The data we gather is held under the premise of legitimate interest
>   for the purpose of providing a professional, useful, and personalised
>   service to relevant parties i.e. you, in a **business-to-business
>   capacity.**
>
> (https://www.insidefoodanddrink.com/index.php/about/privacy-policy)

Does "capacity" mean "relationship"? I searched dictionaries but couldn't find the meaning that fits in this context. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capacity):

> 4 : DUTY, POSITION, ROLE
>   // will be happy to serve in any *capacity*

In this case a "business-to-business capacity" would mean *strictly business*, or something like "in a business-to-business" manner.

Basically, it means that they're only doing this in a business-to-business way, not anything personal, or acting in any way aside from this.